# Can't remember password in Nautilus for SFTP

Tags: nautilus, password, sftp, seahorse

Why is it not possible to remember passwords in Nautilus for SFTP? It works great for FTP with passwords stored with Seahorse. How I can solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Linux server authentication without password using nautilus :***
If you are facing problem for sftp, if it asks for password every time when you try to login to the server using sftp in nautilus, you should add your public key file as authorized_keys on the server.
To do this

```
# scp ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub 192.168.xx.xx:~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

If yu are using RSA keys

```
# scp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub 192.168.xx.xx:~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

where 192.168.xx.xx is IP of the server.

Now if you will try to log into server in nautilus using sftp, it will not ask password.

Comment: It does if you don't specify user@host as mentioned in jiri's answer, if no user is specified, ssh will assume the name of the current working user. If those already match, you have nothing to worry about. Also note that using this answer will overwrite the authorized_keys file on the server, so if you ssh from multiple computers, you may have issues with this.

Answer (score 8):

Try to specify the username in the connect string 
(i.e. sftp://user@host.com)

It uses saved passwords in this way.

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Password and keys (seahorse):
If ftp password is not stored in nautilus :**
By default there should be Login keyring. 
Do not delete it. if it is the only one there, unlock it and make it default. The stored passwords will be added under it.

If login keyring is not there.
Create a keyring. Make it default.
Make it unlock. ( It is a security loop hole if many people access your system)
Now when you select remember forever option in nautilus for ftp.
It will be saved as a stored password under default keyring.

If you are still unable to do it.
Create store password manually under the default keyring and make keyring unlock.

If you do not leave it unlock, it will ask for keyring password every time. The condition is same as it asks for ftp password every time.

I hope it will help.